# Request.InputStream in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use this library in ASP.NET Core: https://github.com/infusion/jQuery-webcam to get the picture taken from a webcam.

In this example, [MVC Capture webcam image, save file path of image to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371106/mvc-capture-webcam-image-save-file-path-of-image-to-the-database), this is what happen:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#Camera").webcam({
                            width: 320,
                            height: 240,
                            mode: "save",
                            swffile: "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jscam.swf")",
                            onTick: function () { },
                            onSave: function () {
                            },
                            onCapture: function () {
                                webcam.save("@Url.Action("Capture", "TrapActivity", new { id = @Model.Id , pid = @Model.PersonId})");
                            },
                            debug: function () { },
                            onLoad: function () { }
                        });
                   });
```

A Controller method called `Capture` is called from the View in this line: `webcam.save("@Url.Action("Capture", "TrapActivity", new { id = @Model.Id , pid = @Model.PersonId})");`

```
public ActionResult Capture(string ID)
    {
        var path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/ID_" + ID + ".jpg" );

        //var path1 = "~/Images/test.jpg;";



        var stream = Request.InputStream;
        string dump;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            dump = reader.ReadToEnd();


        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, String_To_Bytes2(dump));
        }
        else System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, String_To_Bytes2(dump));


        return View(ID);

    }
```

Inside it, there is a `var stream = Request.InputStream;`.

**The problem is that in ASP.NET Core there is NOT a** `Request.InputStream`.

What can I use instead?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[`Request.Body`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.body?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequest_Body) is the stream you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You should use 'Request.Body' instead of InputStream